# delete multiple lines between matched strings

Tags: windows, vbscript, scripting

I writing a script to delete multiple lines in between two matched strings from a file.

Code written as below, but after execution it deletes complete lines. Can anyone suggest how I could implement this?

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

count = 0

strFileName = Wscript.Arguments(0)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForReading)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine

    flag = 0
    If InStr(strLine, "BBB") = 0 Then
        flag = 1
    End If

    If flag = 1 Then
        Exit Do
    End If

    If count = 1 Then
        If flag = 0 Then
            'strNewContents = strNewContents & strLine & vbCrLf
        End If
    End If

    If InStr(strLine, "GGG") = 0 Then
            strLine = ""
            'strNewContents = strNewContents & strLine & vbCrLf
            count = 1
    End If
Loop

objFile.Close

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForWriting)
objFile.Write strNewContents

objFile.Close
}
```

And the file Contains as below

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE
FFF
GGG
HHH
III
JJJ
```

I am expecting a output as

```
AAA 
HHH
III 
JJJ
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following lines cause your script to exit from the loop as soon as it encounters a line *not* containing "BBB", leaving you with an empty variable `strNewContents`:

```
If InStr(strLine, "BBB") = 0 Then
    flag = 1
End If

If flag = 1 Then
    Exit Do
End If
```

What you actually want to do is initialize your flag variable outside the loop, and toggle it whenever you encounter a string matching your criteria:

```
skip = False
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine

    If InStr(strLine, "BBB") > 0 Then skip = True
    If Not skip Then
        If IsEmpty(strNewContents) Then
            strNewContents = strLine
        Else
            strNewContents = strNewContents & vbNewLine & strLine
        End If
    End If
    If InStr(strLine, "GGG") > 0 Then skip = False
Loop
```

Comment: If I read his expected output right, I think he wants GGG to be the indicator for stopping but still exclude it, so the check for skip = false should imo be at the end of the loop, so that one more line gets replaced.